# 'AnyObject' is not identical to '[NSObject : AnyObject]'

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am finding this error in my AppDelegate.swift file and it appears in the AppDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions function. It is raising the error on a line of code that is from the Parse framework.

```
PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions)
```

The error is appearing on the `launchOptions` parameter. I will post the whole function to show that it should be correct. Also when I comment out the line of code the error disappears, but I still really want to be able to use the function and track the analytics. Here is the whole function:

```
func application(application: UIApplication!, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: AnyObject!) -> Bool
{
    // Override point for customization after app launches
    Parse.setApplicationId("removed on purpose", clientKey: "removed on purpose")
    PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions)
    PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebook()

    return true
}
```

I can't seem to find anything that relates to this error. If anyone has some insight I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Xcode 6 beta 7, when you want to call `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, you have to replace:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool {
    /* ... */
}
```

with the following code:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    /* ... */
}
```

The last parameter of this method is no more a NSDictionary but a Dictionary of type `[NSObject: AnyObject]?`. Therefore, you must update your code (including your `trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions:` parameter type).

Comment: Thanks! This was an immediate fix. I see they must have changed the parameter with the beta update. I did forget to mention in the above post that it worked in previous beta's. Thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 1):

The `launchOptions` parameter should be declared as `NSDictionary!` instead of `AnyObject!`:

```
func application(application: UIApplication!, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary!) -> Bool {
    // ...
}
```